# Turning off Deployd dashboard authentication

Tags: authentication, key, deployd, dpd

I have a Deployd application that uses the standard built-in authentication to access the "DEPLOYD DASHBOARD", the one where you enter the key that is revealed by `dpd showkey`.

The whole website is now secured with a username/password requirement to access it.

**How do I turn off the authentication required to access the deployd dashboard?**

---

I've tried deleting the `./.dpd/keys.json` file.
I haven't yet found anything useful in [the docs](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like the best solution, but it does do exactly what is required:

> From : http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server/
>   *Note: If options.env is "development", the dashboard will not require authentication and configuration will not be cached. Make sure to
>   change this to "production" or something similar when deploying.*

---

Example
(`'env': 'development'` has been added):

```
var deployd = require('deployd')
  , options = {
    'port': 7777,
    'db': {
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'name': 'my-database'
    },
    'env': 'development'
   };

var dpd = deployd(options);

dpd.listen();
```

---

I won't mark this as the correct answer in case there is a solution that doesn't require doing something explicitly discouraged (ie. "make sure to change [this] when deploying").